# Unexpected Result When Writing Binary Number To File [C++]

Tags: c++, io, binary, output, binary-data

I'm writing what should be quite a simple function in Linux that takes an integer, converts it to a 4 byte binary string, and writes it to a binary file.

---

The function:

```
void writeToBinaryFile(int number){
    remove("path/fileToWriteTo.img");  //remove outdated version of file

    ofstream output("path/fileToWriteTo.img", ios::binary);

    string binaryString = bitset<32>(number).to_string();
    cout << "BINARY DATA IS " << binaryString << endl; 
    //This looks perfect, an example entry of 81 results in an output of
    //BINARY DATA IS 00000000000000000000000001010001

    output.seekp(0);
    output.write(binaryString.c_str(), 4);  //write these 4 bytes into binary file
    output.close();
}
```

---

This function compiles and runs without an issue, however, when I hexdump the contents of fileToWriteTo.img, the result is wrong. The correct hexdump after running writeToBinaryFile(81) should be 0000 0051, as an example.

However, the ACTUAL hexdump is 3030 3030, and it remains this no matter what integer I pass to writeToBinaryFile(). I feel like there's something fairly trivial I'm missing with this attempt to write the string to a file in binary format, but currently am at a loss for what's happening.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: forget my previous comment. But, FYI, '30' is hexadecimal value of ASCII character '0', and 31 is the value for '1'. So it seems that litteral zeros are being written, which makes sense, as you are writing a binary **string**, and you showed in comments, it starts with a lot of zeros.. Are you sure the output is **exactly** 3030 3030 (4 zeros in text ? )

Comment: Yes, the exact line on the hex dump looks like:

000000: 3030 3030          0000

Read the right column as further away from the others, it's the ascii translation.

Comment: Ow, I just noticed : you are writing 4 bytes.... of text ! So 4 characters '0', which is 4 times the hex value '30'. These might become 'ones', but only for numbers large enough for the 4 first bits to become 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realized that `binaryString` is `"00000000000000000000000001010001"`.

When you use

```
output.write(binaryString.c_str(), 4);
```

you are writing the first 4 characters of the string, which are all `'0'`s. What probably got you confused was that you were expecting to see the number zero but what you asked the program to write is the character `'0'`. The ASCII encoding value for `'0'` is `48` in decimal, which is `0x30`. That's what you are seeing in your file -- four `0x30`s.

If you want to write the number to file in binary, you can use the following, without jumping through the `bitset` hoop.

```
void writeToBinaryFile(int number)
{
    ofstream output("path/fileToWriteTo.img", ios::binary);
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<char cons*>(&number), sizeof(number));
}
```

You don't need the other lines in the function at all.

Comment: Ah, okay, I changed it to write 32 instead of 4, which is certainly better; now see all the characters. Unfortunately, it's still not quite what I was looking for, the hexdump is now:

| 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030
3030 3030 3030 3030 3031 3031 3030 3031 | 

This looks like I wrote the literal string into the file, when what I was hoping to do was write the value 81 as 4 bytes (so the hexdump SHOULD return 0000 0051)

Comment: Responding to your edit: That seems to have worked very well, thank you; my hexdump is now 5100 0000 instead of 0000 0051 which I'm assuming is related to the endianness of the write. I need to figure out how to change this but after that I'll be golden, thank you for the help and I'll accept your answer when possible.

Comment: @MMMMMCK, that's definitely an endianness issue.

Comment: Yes, I figure so. I don't currently know how to change that but will do some research, this answer got me 95% of the way there and I appreciate it.

Comment: @MMMMMCK, glad I was able to help.